# Php array output confusion

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP when I do

```
var_dump($galleryCategoriesThumb);
```

Output is

```
    array(1) {


[0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Gallery"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "190"
      ["photofile"]=>
      string(6) "50.jpg"
      ["gallery_category_id"]=>
      string(2) "58"
    }
  }
}
```

When I do

```
var_dump($galleryCategoriesThumb["photofile"]);
```

I get NULL output. I tried various other options also. 
All I want to do is echo ["photofile"]. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$galleryCategoriesThumb[0]['Gallery']["photofile"]`

Answer (score 1):

Try `var_dump($galleryCategoriesThumb[0]["Gallery"]["photofile"]);`.

It's a 3 dimensions array.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected that var_dump($galleryCategoriesThumb["photofile"]) returns NULL because "photofile" key does not exist in $galleryCategoriesThumb.

To access "photofile", you need a 'full path' in the array as posted by others

```
var_dump($galleryCategoriesThumb[0]["Gallery"]["photofile"]);.
```